# How to print excerpt in the description meta tag

Tags: wordpress

I just need a way to print this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="This in the content" />
```

I have used this code:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php 

$tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
$myExcerpt = str_replace($tags, "", the_excerpt());

echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" />
```

But it prints this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>Content of my plugin. No related posts.</p>
This is the content." />
```

---

If I use this code instead:

```
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php    
    echo get_the_excerpt();  ?>" />
```

It prints this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>Content of my plugin. No related posts.</p>" />
```

---

If I use this code:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php 
$tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
$myExcerpt = str_replace($tags, "", the_excerpt());
echo $myExcerpt; ?>" />
```

It prints this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>Content of my plugin. No related posts.</p>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) (which returns the excerpt) instead of `the_excerpt()` (which echoes the excerpt):

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php 

$tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
$myExcerpt = str_replace($tags, "", get_the_excerpt());

echo $myExcerpt; ?>" />
```

Alternatively, you can simplify things by using [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags) to strip all of the tags:

```
<meta property="og:description" 
      content="<?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ); ?>" />
```

Comment: Just done, but it prints: "Content of my plugin. No related posts." and not "This is the content"

Comment: It's printing the actual excerpt of the current page (i.e. exactly what it's supposed to do). Are you sure you have an excerpt defined on that page? Where have you defined "This is the content"?

Comment: I haven't done anything. But I am using All in One SEO pack and it prints the content correctly in the description meta tag.

Comment: Are you wanting the *content* or the *excerpt*? These are two different things. Read more about excerpts [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt). You'll need to define one in order for one to show up. Otherwise, you'll need to write a function to dynamically set/create one.

Comment: I want the content that prints' ALL in ONE seo pack in the description meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

The ALL in ONE seo pack plugin may insert content into the meta tag but that does not mean it becomes the content, description or excerpt of the page/post. You need to echo the value of the var seo pack uses to store that info.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code snippet on numerous sites and it works well.

```
<meta property="og:description" content='<?php $myExcerpt = strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); echo $myExcerpt; ?>' />
```

Comment: Just done, but it prints this: <meta property="og:description" content="" />

Comment: Are you adding this code into the loop, or outside of the loop? I have the above code **in** the loop, and it's working.

Comment: I have used that code in my_facebook_tags function: add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_facebook_tags' );